# Connecting to Tooling API using Java SOAP

Tags: tooling-api

I have been trying to connect to the tooling API using SOAP and Java, but so far I have not been able to get it to work. I have a Java project with the tooling.jar and wsc-23.jar present, and I have a build script that generates the necessary code. The environment seems to be fine, but I am pretty sure the initialization code for the connection is wrong.

I have not been able to find a tutorial that shows how to set up this connection. However, I did download the [Force.com plugin code from GitHub](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore) and used this as a guide.

Here is my code:

```
  private static void doStuff() throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try (Reader r = new FileReader("connection.properties")) {
      props.load(r);
    }

    // 1. Establish partner connection.
    ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
    partnerConfig.setUsername(props.getProperty("force.user"));
    partnerConfig.setPassword(props.getProperty("force.password") + props.getProperty("force.token"));
    partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint(props.getProperty("force.url.u"));
    partnerConfig.setServiceEndpoint(props.getProperty("force.url.u"));

    PartnerConnection partnerConnection = com.sforce.soap.partner.Connector.newConnection(partnerConfig);

    // 2. Establish tooling connection.
    ConnectorConfig toolingConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
    toolingConfig.setSessionId(partnerConnection.getSessionHeader().getSessionId());
    toolingConfig.setAuthEndpoint(partnerConfig.getAuthEndpoint());
    toolingConfig.setServiceEndpoint(props.getProperty("force.url.t"));

    SoapConnection toolingConnection = com.sforce.soap.tooling.Connector.newConnection(toolingConfig);

    // 3. Use tooling connection. THIS IS THE LINE THAT FAILS
    DescribeGlobalResult res = toolingConnection.describeGlobal();
  }
```

This is the referenced properties file containing configurable settings:

```
force.user=<nope>
force.password=<nope>
force.token=<nope>
force.url.u=https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0/
force.url.t=https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/T/30.0/
```

Finally, here is the Java exception including stack trace:

```
[UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION'
 exceptionMessage='Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService'
]
]

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:628)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:505)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.parseDetail(SoapConnection.java:228)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.createException(SoapConnection.java:202)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:148)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:110)
    at com.sforce.soap.tooling.SoapConnection.describeGlobal(SoapConnection.java:392)
    at Main.doStuff(Main.java:65) <--- This is the line above where I mentioned it blows up
    at Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

What do I need to change in my code so it will successfully login and initialize correctly so I can use the tooling API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a login is done via https://login.salesforce.com, one of the return values of the login is the instance that the username corresponds to such as https://na15.salesforce.com (as part of the overall returned URL). In terms of the Java API you are using, that means that `setAuthEndpoint` can use the fixed login URL but `setServiceEndpoint` has to be given a value returned from the login process.

Some service endpoints are directly available from the `LoginResult`, but the Force.com IDE obtains the tooling one by replacing the "u" with a "T" in a rather fragile looking way [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/a2619f2318049967d224c8f71a9a6a87c446e476/com.salesforce.ide.core/src/com/salesforce/ide/core/remote/Connection.java#L641).

So your code might look something like this:

```
ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
partnerConfig.setManualLogin(true);

PartnerConnection partnerConnection = com.sforce.soap.partner.Connector.newConnection(
        partnerConfig);
LoginResult lr = partnerConnection.login(
        props.getProperty("force.user"),
        props.getProperty("force.password") + props.getProperty("force.token")
        );

ConnectorConfig toolingConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
toolingConfig.setSessionId(lr.getSessionId());
toolingConfig.setServiceEndpoint(lr.getServerUrl().replace('u', 'T'));

SoapConnection toolingConnection = com.sforce.soap.tooling.Connector.newConnection(
        toolingConfig);
```

Comment: This did it. Using the different service endpoint fixed it. I made some other minor changes such as `replace("/u/", "/T/")` which I believe is less fragile than a straight character replacement, even if still less than ideal.